# Substring in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a line in xml:

```
<P4PORT>facebook.com</P4PORT>
```

How to get the value (facebook.com) in the last `<P4PORT>` tag. I used like this:

```
for /f "tokens=1" %%R in ('findstr /c:"<P4Port>" file.xml') do echo %%R
PAUSE
```

But it gave me whole string `<P4PORT>facebook.com</P4PORT>`. Please tell how to achieve this using batch file.

Comment: maybe you want to create a vbscript which queries the XML (XPATH) for the desired value and print it out. From the back file, you could read this again using your for() loop

Comment: Try `for /f "tokens=2 delims=<>" %%R in ('findstr /L /I /C:"<P4Port>" "file.xml"') do set "LAST=%%R"`, afterwards `echo(%LAST%` (supposing there are no leading white-spaces in the line of text)...

Answer (score 0):

Using `RegExp` with a vbscript :

```
strData = "<P4PORT>facebook.com</P4PORT>"
With New RegExp
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = "<P4PORT>((.|\n)*?)</P4PORT>"
    Set Matches = .Execute(strData)
End With
If Matches.Count > 0 Then strText = Matches(0).SubMatches(0)
wscript.echo strText
```

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to parse XML or any other structured data as a hierarchical object, rather than as complicated text to hack and scrape.  That way you aren't dependent upon the formatting of the data, whether it's beautified, minified, or whatever.  Simplest solution would be to put this in your batch script:

```perl
for /f "delims=" %%I in (
    'powershell "([xml](gc filename.xml)).SelectSingleNode('//P4PORT/text()').data"'
) do set "P4PORT=%%I"

echo %P4PORT%
```

If you value speed over simplicity, you can invoke JScript to parse the XML as well.  Save this batch + JScript hybrid script with a .bat extension.

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off & setlocal

for /f "delims=" %%I in (
    'cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" "filename.xml"'
) do set "P4PORT=%%I"

echo %P4PORT%

goto :EOF
@end // end Batch / begin JScript hybrid code

var xml = WSH.CreateObject('MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0');
xml.load(WSH.Arguments(0));
WSH.Echo(xml.selectSingleNode('//P4PORT/text()').data);
```

Answer (score 0):

This thing worked for me and is also an easy solution. But thanks for your answers.

for /f "tokens=3 delims=><  " %%a in ('TYPE %connectionfile% ^| FIND ""') do set P4PORT=%%a